# Store UIImagePickerController Image locally in App Assets

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, userdefaults

I'm trying to assign a profile picture in app through a UIImagePickerController. However, I need to figure out a way to store the image so it still appears after the apps restarts.

I've tried other methods, primarily the ones that use UIImagePNGRepresentation. But this no longer exists in Swift 4+, so I need some other method.

```
   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
    {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true)

        profilePicture = info[.editedImage] as! UIImage
    }
}
```

What I want to do, is still display the image as a profile picture. But when the app restarts, still have the image appear. Since this is from the camera roll, I can't store it in the .xcassets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving image and then loading it in Swift (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344822/saving-image-and-then-loading-it-in-swift-ios)

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that this really is how you are getting your image:

```
profilePicture = info[.editedImage] as! UIImage
```

OK, so at that moment you know what the image is. So store it to disk at a known location (e.g. Documents) under a known name. On future launches, all you have to do is look to see if the image is there and use it if it is.

> primarily the ones that use UIImagePNGRepresentation. But this no longer exists in Swift 4+

Yes, it does, and that is the way to extract the data and store it to disk. All that has happened is that the *name* has changed and it is now a UIImage method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624096-pngdata