# macOS: SwiftUI: MenuItem for taking a screenshot of WKWebView and save it to ~/Pictures with a timestamp?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, wkwebview

I'm creating a macOS SwiftUI app that opens a WKWebView to a specific URL.

Now I'm attempting to make a MenuItem mapped to a function that takes a screenshot of the WKWebView window, and saves it to ~/Pictures with a timestamp.

I tried to look for this via tutorials but only found [iOS WKSnapShot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wksnapshotconfiguration) type stuff.

While the "MenuItem" -> bind to -> First Responder -> `@IBAction` is something I'm kind of familiar with now, I'm not entirely sure how to call the WKWebView snapshotting and how to define it's timestamped name.

```
    @IBAction func takeSnapshot(with snapshotConfiguration: WKSnapshotConfiguration?,
    completionHandler: @escaping (NSImage?, Error?) -> Void)
    {
}
```

This started shooting errors at me: `@IBAction methods must have 1 argument`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the snapshot function on the webView. To get the webView snapshot function to be available, you need to make it available in the `AppDelegate.swift`

Then you can save it by using `saveImage` - [which is linked in the handy function at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53894441/263858).

```
public let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()
@IBAction func takeSnapshot(with snapshotConfiguration: WKSnapshotConfiguration,
    completionHandler: @escaping (NSImage *snapshotImage) -> Void)
    {
        self.webView.takeSnapshot(with: snapshotConfiguration) { image, error in
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
                    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss"
        name = (formatter.string(from: Date()) as NSString) as String
            if let image = image {
                saveImage(name, image)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I added `public let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView()` above the `@IBAction` so the webView error stopped occurring. However, that did not change these errors: "Use of unresolved identifier 'saveImage'", `@IBAction methods must have 1 argument` and "Expected ';' separator" and "Expected type".

Comment: after adding the saveImage from the linked link, and modifying each UIImage to NSImage, I'm still seeing `Value of 'NSImage' has no member 'jpegData'` from saveImage, and also the actual ibaction shoots `Missing argument labels 'imageName:image:' in call` and `@IBAction methods must have 1 argument` and `Expected type` below the ibaction line.