# How do I get list of Images saved in a folder?

Tags: swift, nsdocumentdirectory, document-directory

I have to get list of images, which i have saved in a directory as a sub-directory.
First i created a document directory, then inside i have some folders, In the folder i have saved images(like sub-directory). Now i want to get list of images to show on a UITableView.

I used following code to save

```
func saveImageToDocumentDirectory(image: UIImage ) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileName = txtfield.text! + ".png"
    let fileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(directoryName).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    
    if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0),!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path){
        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL)
            print("file saved")
            fileNameArray.append(fileName)
        } catch {
            print("error saving file:", error)
        }
    }
}
```

So, Now I want to get list of images saved here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344822/saving-image-and-then-loading-it-in-swift-ios
duplicate question

Comment: Hi Jin, this is not duplicate question. In this question i want to get the images as SubDirectories. But the above link gives access of images from document directory directly. 
But yes i have get the list that i wanted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you're appending `directoryName` when composing your `fileURL`, you can get `directoryURL` and read its files:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let documentsURL = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let directoryURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(directoryName)
do {
    let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    // process files
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```