# Export chat with media and text in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Hi can someone tell me how to export chat of single user, like WhatsApp.

I am new to this work, Please help ,thanks in advance

Comment: create a table of sqlite in app directory convert it to csv and export it

Comment: I have sqlite but help me out with code so that would be appreciated

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed can you help me creating that

Comment: its a big task time consuming without knowing full criteria i can't help here on ask. 
If you create sqlite table then figure out how create csv of any other text document file

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed thanks for quick response ,how can I save text and images into filemanager and convert it to zip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354779/14699332 this how you can save and reterive image