# How to load image from Photos after saving it via camera?

Tags: ios, swift, photo

I have saved my camera captured photo to Photos and then trying to access it. I am able to successfully save it using PHPhotoLibrary and once saved I get a path like this `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0048.JPG`. Now I need to load this path inside an `UIImageView`

I tried the below code

```
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0048.JPG"))
let image = UIImage(data: data)
imageView.image = image
```

but my app crash saying

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “IMG_0048.JPG” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/file:/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0048.JPG, NSUnderlyingError=0x280c545a0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

I tried using `kingfisher` library but it does not load the image as well using `imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(fileURLWithPath: imageUrl))` but image is not getting displayed

Another way which I tried was using below code, I am extracting image name from the path and then sending to load function

```
var documentsUrl: URL {
        return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    }
    
    private func load(fileName: String) -> UIImage? {
        let fileURL = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        do {
            let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            return UIImage(data: imageData)
        } catch {
            print("Error loading image : \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

and then using

`imageView.image = load(fileName: "IMG_0048.JPG")` but it does not display the image as well

Comment: You had the image data before saving to Photos, so it's not neccessary to load it back I think

Comment: I am capturing the image in separate view controller and displaying it in some other view controller. Sending Image data via view controller is bad practice so I am just sending the path as its lightweight as compared to data

Comment: It's not bad practice, it's faster than storing to disk and re-loading it to memory. Using delegate pattern you can transfer data between View Controllers.

Comment: If you still want to 'store and load', you should write it to the App's Document folder. The path in the Document folder is accessible, whereas /var/mobile/ is non-accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your approaches are wrong. They are requesting a local data using local url and your url is from `Photos`, which need to use `PHPhotoLibrary`.
I assume you are using `UIImagePickerController` to take a photo, you can use `PHAsset` to request image data

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    let phAsset = info[.phAsset] as! PHAsset
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
        if status == .authorized {
            let imageManager = PHImageManager.default()
            imageManager.requestImageData(for: phAsset, options: nil) { data, _, _, _ in
                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                // Your image
            }
        } else {
            // Access to the photo library is not authorized.
        }
    }
}
```

As @JeremyP's answer, after save a photo, you should save the `localId` instead of `fullSizeImageURL` and use this code to retrieve the photo

```
func getPhotoInLibrary(localIdentifiers: String, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    let result = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [localId], options: nil)
    guard let asset = result.firstObject else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { data, _, _, _ in
        if let data = data {
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            completion(image)
        } else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't help me. I am not using UIImagePickerController as I need to customise the captured image from camera so I am using AVCapturePhotoOutput,AVCaptureSession etc and once image is captured I am using PHPhotoLibrary to save it to photos which works as well then I need to load the image to an image view which does not work

Comment: How can you get that url? @BraveEvidence

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61504980/9552485

Comment: @BraveEvidence in the code you linked `localId` is the id of the image in the Photo library. You can use that id to find its `PHAsset` instead of using the image picker.

Comment: requestImageData is deprecated in iOS 13

Comment: you can use `func requestImage(for asset: PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, options: PHImageRequestOptions?, resultHandler: @escaping (UIImage?, [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void) -> PHImageRequestID` @BraveEvidence